# Is there any way/control to show data grid empty rows lines like this in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want this data grid in WPF. In wpf default behavior only rows lines are shown when data is there other wise its blank. Also when data grid is filled user is able to add data in last row which is most down row in grid.[image: What i want]

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows without content, what you would do is add an item to the DataGrid's ItemsSource with empty values. If you bind to your ItemsSource correctly, this should work by default. I can see no reason why the DataGrid wouldn't show these rows.

To disable adding new rows, add

```
CanUserAddRows="False"
```

to your DataGrid tag